# XSLT - Table to continue in 3 columns on the same page

Tags: css, xslt, pdf

Hopefully someone has done this - I need a 3 column page (side-by-side) with a two column table (with the headers) to fill the three columns. The table is fairly long and I need it to wrap/continue from the first column on the page to the second column and on to the third and then continue to the next page in the same fashion. Right now I can only get the table to show in one column on the page and it continues on the next page.  The final output is a printed PDF page.

Comment: Use fo block span = all and insert your table in that block. The table will span all three text flow columns until it ends. If you show sample markup we can help you better.

Comment: Thx Kevin - let me give this a try, just kind of needed a jumping off point. I'll let you know how this progresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using span="all" is the way to cause some in flow content to span all the columns of a multi-column document. For brevity in answering, I am posting a picture of the XSL FO for something like this.[image: Sample XSL FO three column with spanning table]

Comment: Hi Kevin, sorry for the delay - I have other issues with this page with the columns - I'm convinced that what you explained will work, just need to get the page to work to begin with. thanks for the answer